# WebAPI: Multiple Routes for the Same Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

Can a controller action have multiple routes?  I.e.

```
[Route("api/oldroute/dosomethingawesome")]
[Route("api/newroute/dosomethingawesome")] 
public IEnumerable<string> DoSomethingAwesome()
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code snippet?

Comment: Haha!  Good point - I did after I originally asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for the GET actions, The documentation says you can have multiple routes on a Get action.